# Value of Variable doesn´t be passed to function

Tags: jquery

My Problem is, that the value is passed correctly to the variable, but I think something is missing, because when changing the value of #sol, the animation time, doesn´t change. Maybe I´ve got to work with .on(change.... ?

```
$(function() {
var speed = $('#sol').val();
    $(document).on('click', '#engage', function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, speed);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});


<form id="speed">
    <select id="sol" style="display:block;">
        <option value="800000">1</option>
        <option value="400000">2</option>
        <option value="200000">4</option>
        <option value="100000">8</option>
        <option value="50000">16</option>
        <option value="32000">25</option>
        <option value="16000">50</option>
        <option value="100000000000">100</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no live mapping between the value of `#sol` element and the variable `speed` which will result in an updation of the value of the variable when the select elements value is changed

Instead you an read the value of the select element when you want to use it in the click handler

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#engage', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, +$('#sol').val());
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

---

Another solution is to use a change handler which will update the value of the variable whenever it is changed

```
$(function () {
    var speed = $('#sol').val();

    $('#sol').change(function () {
        speed = $(this).val();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#engage', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, speed);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the one without variable works fine, the solution with the change handler doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#engage', function(event){
    var speed = $('#sol').val(); // assign value to speed when ever user click on the element with id engage 
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
    }, speed);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

---

Problem you are setting `speed` value and not updating it with the value changed .